# foldLeft argument signature :o

Tags: scala

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (x => contains(t,x) || contains(s,x))
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = (x => x==elem)
```

...

```
val s1 = singletonSet(1)
val s2 = singletonSet(2)
val s3 = singletonSet(3)

// works
val s = List(s1,s2,s3).foldLeft( union(_,_) )

// error
val s = List(s1,s2,s3).foldLeft( union )
```

Why does the second way not work? It says the signature of my union is wrong!

But it works if I use wildcard arguments like `union(_, _)`. Can't I just use `union` like in the second example?

Comment: what dummy arguments do you mean? who do you mean with "her"?

Comment: @katie try to maintain a bit of formality in your questions. No need for emoticons etc. Just makes the question harder to read. Also try to avoid leaving out subjects (it's not always obvious what you mean with he / she / it).

Answer (score 1):

`foldLeft` is defined like this:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

The first argument is the 'zero', so the element which is passed first into the fold function (the second argument). So in your first case you are passing the function `union` as a zero argument (and only argument). It becomes clear when you add type annotations:

```
val sU1: (((Set, Set) => Set, Set) => (Set, Set) => Set) => (Set, Set) => Set = List(s1,s2,s3).foldLeft( union(_,_) )
```

If you only give the zero argument to `foldLeft` (keyword currying) you get a function, taking a function as parameter. The parameter function takes elements of types of your elements in the list and the zero argument (so a `Set` and the type of union -> `(Set, Set) => Set`) and returns something of the type of your zero argument (so in your first case again a function of type `(Set, Set) => Set`).

What you probably want is:

```
val sU2: Set = List(s1,s2,s3).foldLeft(singletonSet(0))(union)
```

You need to pass a valid zero argument and then you can use the union function as you want to.

Another option, if you don't want to provide an initial value is `reduceLeft`, which takes the first element in the list as an initial value:

```
val sU3: Set = List(s1,s2,s3).reduceLeft(union)
```

I think that makes more sense in your case.